# A fully non-blocking actor model?

Tags: java, multithreading, nonblocking

So recently I am looking around my actor model. My tasks needs to be serially executed on each queue i.e. 1 task can only start execute after all the tasks submitted before it are finished; and no parallel is allowed on a single queue.

Most of them uses utilities like ThreadPoolExecutor, SingleThreadExecutor etc from the standard JDK. However, on looking further into those executors, it seems to me that ReentrantLock are inevitably used while checking the exit condition i.e. if this is the first task added and the job needs to be kicked on; and if this is the last running task and the scheduling can pause a bit.

I tried to implement this part by using all non-blocking i.e. compareAndSet() but all my attempts failed. I also tried to look for other implementations online, but seems they all contain at least 1 lock.

So my question is, is it actually possible to implement such an actor model with only non-blocking and compareAndSet related operations? If yes, how?

Comment: Is there a client that is waiting for the completion of all tasks?

Comment: that is, even there is no jobs, a working thread should not block and still hold a processor? Why?

Comment: If there is no work to do, you should not be making up more by looping, sucking up CPU and memory-bandwidth by avoiding blocking inter-thread comms.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe it clearly. The thread should essentially do wait() or equivalent when there is no task available; but the first task put into the queue should do yield() or equivalent. Now its the wait() and yield() here which need basically a synchronized() block to check if there is no more tasks AND the thread is running/not running. I couldn't think of a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-engineering here. Yes a pure actor model is possible, but the work necessary to implement it is abysmal (at least in Java).

If you use an Executor and create a new Runnable for every event that occurs and then distribute this to the Executor, then yes you will have some blocking for those threads if they need to be put on hold during idle time, but this isn't an issue, it is actually a good thing.

The alternative would be to re-create the thread every time you need one, which is way more costly than simply putting an existing one on hold. And that blocking time is anyway only subtracted from idle time - with no downside - as each thread will immediately continue without blocking if there is further work to do.

Pseudo-code for how the executor's threads work:

```
while (this.isInterrupted() == false) {
  while (taskList.hasMore()) {
    process(taskList.next());
  }
  taskList.waitForTasks();
}
```